# SharePoint 2010 get all the files and folders recursively

Tags: soap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, soap-client

Post: http://******.com/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx

SOAPAction:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection

request:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListCollection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using above i get a list of all the top level folders/lists available

After getting all the top level folders using the same information i want to get all the lower level folders and their files using soap requests.

What i have tried is:

Post: http://******.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Soapaction:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems

Request:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>test1</listName>
     <QueryOptions> 
           <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
           <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
           <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>               
        </QueryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

which should have returned all the folders and sub folders inside listname test1.
**But again it returned only top level files and folders.
What expected is: to return all the files and folders recursively under list** **test1**
Thanks in advance